# Autorotate Modal view

Tags: ios, orientation, modalviewcontroller, ipad, autorotate

I have created a modal view in Portrait mode. when it is in lanscape mode it is not rotating.
How to rotate a modal view from Portrait to Lanscape in splitViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. The modal view is loaded from the DetailViewController, and when the iPad is rotated, the modal view disappears from view completely.

The closest I've come to a fix is, after rotating, to check whether a modal view was loaded, and then reload it, like so:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if(self.modalViewController)
        [self.modalViewController.view.window reloadInputViews];
}
```